# SwiftUI: Putting multiple BindableObjects into Environment

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, swiftui

In `SwiftUI` it is possible to use the `environmentObject` method of the View object to put a single `BindableObject` into the environment.

What if I want to put multiple `BindableObjects` at the same time into the environment? I don't see any solution for this in the SwiftUI documentation. I don't want to have to pass the objects in the constructor.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The call to `environmentObject()` returns a (modified) view, therefore you can *chain* the calls to put multiple objects into the environment. Example:

```
 let rootView = ContentView()
     .environmentObject(firstBindable)
     .environmentObject(secondBindable)
```

Comment: How are the objects referenced? Is there supporting docs to learn more?

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: I don't know how it is implemented. I watched the WWDC video about SwiftUI, and figured out the rest by try and error.

Comment: Based off of compiler errors, it seems it looks for an object matching the same type. And it also uses the first `environmentObject` attached when there are multiple of the same type.

Comment: Probably using the type name as the key. This is a valid use case when there are multiple views of the same type. For example, calculating the light value difference between two camera exposures (very common for photographers, I'm speaking from experience). https://www.scantips.com/lights/exposurecalc.html

Comment: I wish I could click the up arrow 50 times!  This was KILLING me.  Thank you!