# How to tell SwiftUI views to bind to nested ObservableObjects

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have a SwiftUI view that takes in an EnvironmentObject called `appModel`. It then reads the value `appModel.submodel.count` in its `body` method. I expect this to bind my view to the property `count` on `submodel` so that it re-renders when the property updates, but this does not seem to happen.

Is this a bug? And if not, what is the idiomatic way to have views bind to nested properties of environment objects in SwiftUI?

Specifically, my model looks like this...

```
class Submodel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var submodel: Submodel = Submodel()
}
```

And my view looks like this...

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel

  var body: some View {
    Text("Count: \(appModel.submodel.count)")
      .onTapGesture {
        self.appModel.submodel.count += 1
      }
  }
}
```

When I run the app and click on the label, the `count` property does increase but the label does not update.

I can fix this by passing in `appModel.submodel` as a property to `ContentView`, but I'd like to avoid doing so if possible.

Comment: I'm also designing my app like this. I usually have a global App object in past app development. Does anyone else think this design of a super "App" class as the environment variable will become standard practice? I was also considering using multiple EnvironmentObjects but that's been hard to maintain.

Comment: DO NOT use reference types for `@Published`. The property wrapper will not emit an `objectWillChange` if a member of its wrapped type changes.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Nested models does not work yet in SwiftUI, but you could do something like this

```
class SubModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var submodel: SubModel = SubModel()
    
    var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    init() {
        anyCancellable = submodel.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] (_) in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    } 
}
```

Basically your `AppModel` catches the event from `SubModel` and send it further to the `View`.

Edit:

If you do not need `SubModel` to be class, then you could try something like this either:

```
struct SubModel{
    var count = 0
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var submodel: SubModel = SubModel()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! When you say "Nested models does not work yet in SwiftUI", do you know for sure that they are planned?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in my opinion it should work, I also use something similar in my proj, so if I'll find a better approach I'll come with an edit

Comment: @SorinLica Should `Submodel` be `ObservableObject ` type?

Comment: One thing I just notice that without weak self, the model deinit will never call  `anyCancellable = submodel.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] (_) in self?.objectWillChange.send() }`

Comment: I would like to add that the AnyCancellable Type is defined in the Combine Framework. 99% of you guys knew this I guess, I had to google...

Comment: if you think an observable object cannot have a related observable object then you have a problem with your View code because it works fine.

Comment: In my case i have a list of ObservableObject with active changes, if i would sink on changes in nested objects this would trigger reload entire list when i need to refresh only one row. So i would have freezes

Comment: See following post: https://arthurhammer.de/2020/03/combine-optional-flatmap/ . Solving Combine-Way with the $ publisher.

Comment: I personally prefer the second one. It is better to create nested struct instead of nested class.

Comment: @JeanNicolas Link's broken. 

Answer (score 28):

Sorin Lica's solution can solve the problem but this will result in code smell when dealing with complicated views.

What seems to better advice is to look closely at your views, and revise them to make more, and more targeted views. Structure your views so that each view displays a single level of the object structure, matching views to the classes that conform to `ObservableObject`. In the case above, you could make a view for displaying `Submodel` (or even several views) that display's the property from it that you want show. Pass the property element to that view, and let it track the publisher chain for you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel

  var body: some View {
    SubView(submodel: appModel.submodel)
  }
}

struct SubView: View {
  @ObservedObject var submodel: Submodel

  var body: some View {
      Text("Count: \(submodel.count)")
      .onTapGesture {
        self.submodel.count += 1
      }
  }
}
```

This pattern implies making more, smaller, and focused views, and lets the engine inside SwiftUI do the relevant tracking. Then you don't have to deal with the book keeping, and your views potentially get quite a bit simpler as well.

You can check for more detail in this post: https://rhonabwy.com/2021/02/13/nested-observable-objects-in-swiftui/

Comment: The answer in this page is golden. Thank you. Not only it explains the issue, and is more elegant than the whole passing the objectWillChange upstream hell, which, like mentioned, will cause many unnecessary UI updates. https://rhonabwy.com/2021/02/13/nested-observable-objects-in-swiftui/

Comment: This is probably "the SwiftUI way".

Comment: This solution is great, however it doesn't seem to work on iOS13

Comment: Great answer. Much easier to go with the intended pattern here

Answer (score 10):

I wrote about this recently on my blog: [Nested Observable Objects](https://rhonabwy.com/2021/02/13/nested-observable-objects-in-swiftui/). The gist of the solution, if you really want a hierarchy of ObservableObjects, is to create your own top-level [Combine Subject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subject) to conform to the [ObservableObject protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject), and then encapsulate any logic of what you want to trigger updates into imperative code that updates that subject.

For example, if you had two "nested" classes, such as

```swift
class MainThing : ObservableObject {
    @Published var element : SomeElement
    init(element : SomeElement) {
        self.element = element
    }
}
```

```swift
class SomeElement : ObservableObject {
    @Published var value : String
    init(value : String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Then you could expand the top-level class (`MainThing` in this case) to:

```swift
class MainThing : ObservableObject {
    @Published var element : SomeElement
    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    init(element : SomeElement) {
        self.element = element
        self.cancellable = self.element.$value.sink(
            receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Which grabs a publisher from the embedded `ObservableObject`, and sends an update into the local published when the property `value` on `SomeElement` class is modified. You can extend this to use CombineLatest for publishing streams from multiple properties, or any number of variations on the theme.

This isn't a "just do it" solution though, because the logical conclusion of this pattern is after you've grown that hierarchy of views, you're going to end up with potentially huge swatches of a View subscribed to that publisher that will invalidate and redraw, potentially causing excessive, sweeping redraws and relatively poor performance on updates. I would advise seeing if you can refactor your views to be specific to a class, and match it to just that class, to keep the "blast radius" of SwiftUI's view invalidation minimized.

Comment: The advice at the end (and in the blog post) is absolutely golden. I was going down a rabbit hole of chained `objectWillChange` invocations, but instead I just had to refactor a single view to take an `@ObservedObject`... thanks @heckj :)

Answer (score 7):

If you need to nest observable objects here is the best way to do it that I could find.

```swift
class ChildModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published
    var count = 0
    
}

class ParentModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published
    private var childWillChange: Void = ()
    
    let child = ChildModel()
    
    init() {
        child.objectWillChange.assign(to: &$childWillChange)
    }
    
}
```

Instead of subscribing to child's objectWillChange publisher and firing parent's publisher, you assign values to published property and parent's objectWillChange triggers automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I liked solution by [sorin-lica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58406402/521197). Based upon that I've decided to implement a custom `Property Wrapper` (following this amazing [article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/accessing-a-swift-property-wrappers-enclosing-instance/)) named `NestedObservableObject` to make that solution more developer friendly.

This allow to write your model in the following way

```swift
class Submodel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
  @NestedObservableObject var submodel: Submodel = Submodel()
}
```

Property Wrapper implementation

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct NestedObservableObject<Value : ObservableObject> {
    
    static subscript<T: ObservableObject>(
        _enclosingInstance instance: T,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Value>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Self>
    ) -> Value {
        
        get {
            if instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].cancellable == nil, let publisher = instance.objectWillChange as? ObservableObjectPublisher   {
                instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].cancellable =
                    instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].storage.objectWillChange.sink { _ in
                            publisher.send()
                    }
            }
            
            return instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].storage
         }
         set {
             
             if let cancellable = instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].cancellable {
                 cancellable.cancel()
             }
             if let publisher = instance.objectWillChange as? ObservableObjectPublisher   {
                 instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].cancellable =
                     newValue.objectWillChange.sink { _ in
                             publisher.send()
                     }
             }
             instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].storage = newValue
         }
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable,
        message: "This property wrapper can only be applied to classes"
    )
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { fatalError() }
        set { fatalError() }
    }
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var storage: Value

    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        storage = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

I've published code on [gist](https://gist.github.com/bsorrentino/3bd923b85ce0e8421b59c87f8f470874)

Answer (score 3):

`@Published` is not designed for reference types so it's a programming error to add it on the `AppModel` property, even though the compiler or runtime doesn't complain. What would've been intuitive is adding `@ObservedObject` like below but sadly this silently does nothing:

```
class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var submodel: SubModel = SubModel()
}
```

I'm not sure if disallowing nested `ObservableObjects` was intentional by SwiftUI or a gap to be filled in the future. Wiring up the parent and child objects as suggested in the other answers is very messy and hard to maintain. What seems to be the idea of SwiftUI is to split up the views into smaller ones and pass the child object to the subview:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel

    var body: some View {
        SubView(model: appModel.submodel)
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: SubModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Count: \(model.count)")
            .onTapGesture {
                model.count += 1
            }
    }
}

class SubModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    var submodel: SubModel = SubModel()
}
```

The submodel mutations actually propagate when passing into a subview!

However, there's nothing stopping another dev from calling `appModel.submodel.count` from the parent view which is annoying there's no compiler warning or even some Swift way to enforce not doing this.

Source: https://rhonabwy.com/2021/02/13/nested-observable-objects-in-swiftui/

Comment: The answer in this page is golden. Thank you. Not only it explains the issue, and is more elegant than the whole passing the objectWillChange upstream hell, which, like mentioned, will cause many unnecessary UI updates. https://rhonabwy.com/2021/02/13/nested-observable-objects-in-swiftui/

Comment: For sure that's the best answer cause I think the whole concept of Propertywrappers is using them on value types, not reference types.

Answer (score 1):

All three ViewModels can communicate and update

```
// First ViewModel
class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
var facadeViewModel: FacadeViewModels

facadeViewModel.firstViewModelUpdateSecondViewModel()
}

// Second ViewModel
class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {

}

// FacadeViewModels Combine Both 

import Combine // so you can update thru nested Observable Objects

class FacadeViewModels: ObservableObject { 
lazy var firstViewModel: FirstViewModel = FirstViewModel(facadeViewModel: self)
  @Published var secondViewModel = secondViewModel()
}

var anyCancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init() {
firstViewModel.objectWillChange.sink {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }.store(in: &anyCancellable)

secondViewModel.objectWillChange.sink {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }.store(in: &anyCancellable)
}

func firstViewModelUpdateSecondViewModel() {
     //Change something on secondViewModel
secondViewModel
}
```

Thank you Sorin for Combine solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that I believe is more ellegant than subscribing to the child (view)models. It's weird and I don't have an explanation for why it works.

## Solution

Define a base class that inherits from `ObservableObject`, and defines a method `notifyWillChange()` that simply calls `objectWillChange.send()`. Any derived class then overrides `notifyWillChange()` and calls the parent's `notifyWillChange()` method.
Wrapping `objectWillChange.send()` in a method is required, otherwise the changes to `@Published` properties do not cause the any `View`s to update. It may have something to do with how `@Published` changes are detected. I believe SwiftUI/Combine use reflection under the hood...

I have made some slight additions to OP's code:

- `count` is wrapped in a method call which calls `notifyWillChange()` before the counter is incremented. This is required for the propagation of the changes.
- `AppModel` contains one more `@Published` property, `title`, which is used for the navigation bar's title. This showcases that `@Published` works for both the parent object and the child (in the example below, updated 2 seconds after the model is initialized).

## Code

### Base Model

```
class BaseViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func notifyWillUpdate() {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

### Models

```
class Submodel: BaseViewModel {
    @Published var count = 0
}


class AppModel: BaseViewModel {
    @Published var title: String = "Hello"
    @Published var submodel: Submodel = Submodel()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.notifyWillChange() // XXX: objectWillChange.send() doesn't work!
            self.title = "Hello, World"
        }
    }

    func increment() {
        notifyWillChange() // XXX: objectWillChange.send() doesn't work!
        submodel.count += 1
    }

    override func notifyWillChange() {
        super.notifyWillChange()
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

### The View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appModel: AppModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Count: \(appModel.submodel.count)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.appModel.increment()
            }.navigationBarTitle(appModel.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
import Combine

extension ObservableObject {
    func propagateWeakly<InputObservableObject>(
        to inputObservableObject: InputObservableObject
    ) -> AnyCancellable where
        InputObservableObject: ObservableObject,
        InputObservableObject.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher
    {
        objectWillChange.propagateWeakly(to: inputObservableObject)
    }
}

extension Publisher where Failure == Never {
    public func propagateWeakly<InputObservableObject>(
        to inputObservableObject: InputObservableObject
    ) -> AnyCancellable where
        InputObservableObject: ObservableObject,
        InputObservableObject.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher
    {
        sink { [weak inputObservableObject] _ in
            inputObservableObject?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

So on the call side:

```
class TrackViewModel {
    private let playbackViewModel: PlaybackViewModel
    
    private var propagation: Any?
    
    init(playbackViewModel: PlaybackViewModel) {
        self.playbackViewModel = playbackViewModel
        
        propagation = playbackViewModel.propagateWeakly(to: self)
    }
    
    ...
}
```

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/Czajnikowski/4c7100f10fb3d8da22ee17bdbac00e9c).

Answer (score 0):

See following post for a solution: [arthurhammer.de/2020/03/combine-optional-flatmap][1] .  This is solving the question in a Combine-Way with the $ publisher.

Assume `class Foto` has an annotation struct and and annotation publisher, which publish an annotation struct. Within Foto.sample(orientation: .Portrait) the annotation struct gets "loaded" through the annotation publisher asynchroniously. Plain vanilla combine.... but to get that into a View & ViewModel, use this:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foto: Foto
    @Published var annotation: LCPointAnnotation
    @Published var annotationFromFoto: LCPointAnnotation

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

        
    init() {
      self.foto = Foto.sample(orientation: .Portrait)
      self.annotation = LCPointAnnotation()
      self.annotationFromFoto = LCPointAnnotation()
    
      self.foto.annotationPublisher
        .replaceError(with: LCPointAnnotation.emptyAnnotation)
        .assign(to: \.annotation, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    
      $foto
        .flatMap { $0.$annotation }
        .replaceError(with: LCPointAnnotation.emptyAnnotation)
        .assign(to: \.annotationFromFoto, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    
    }
 }
```

Note:  [1]: https://arthurhammer.de/2020/03/combine-optional-flatmap/

Pay attention the $annotation above within the flatMap, it's a publisher!

```
 public class Foto: ObservableObject, FotoProperties, FotoPublishers {
   /// use class not struct to update asnyc properties!
   /// Source image data
   @Published public var data: Data
   @Published public var annotation = LCPointAnnotation.defaultAnnotation
   ......
   public init(data: Data)  {
      guard let _ = UIImage(data: data),
            let _ = CIImage(data: data) else {
           fatalError("Foto - init(data) - invalid Data to generate          CIImage or UIImage")
       }
      self.data = data
      self.annotationPublisher
        .replaceError(with: LCPointAnnotation.emptyAnnotation)
        .sink {resultAnnotation in
            self.annotation = resultAnnotation
            print("Foto - init annotation = \(self.annotation)")
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a var in your top view that is equal to a function or published var in your top class. Then pass it and bind it to every sub view. If it changes in any sub view then the top view will be updated.

Code Structure:

```
struct Expense : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var type: String
    var cost: Double
    var isDeletable: Bool
}

class Expenses: ObservableObject{ 
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var items: [Expense] 

    init() {
        name = "John Smith"
        items = [
            Expense(name: "Lunch", type: "Business", cost: 25.47, isDeletable: true),
            Expense(name: "Taxi", type: "Business", cost: 17.0, isDeletable: true),
            Expense(name: "Sports Tickets", type: "Personal", cost: 75.0, isDeletable: false)
        ]
    }
    
    func totalExpenses() -> Double { }      
}

class ExpenseTracker: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var expenses: Expenses
    
    init() {
        name = "My name"
        expenses = Expenses()
    }    

    func getTotalExpenses() -> Double { }
}
```

Views:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myTracker: ExpenseTracker
    @State var totalExpenses: Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section (header: Text("Main")) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("name:")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("", text: $myTracker.name)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .keyboardType(.default)
                    }                         
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(myExpenses: myTracker.expenses, totalExpenses: $totalExpenses),
                                   label: {
                                       Text("View Expenses")
                                   })
                }                
                Section (header: Text("Results")) {
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Total Expenses")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(totalExpenses, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My Expense Tracker")
            .font(.subheadline)
        }      
        .onAppear{
            totalExpenses = myTracker.getTotalExpenses()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myExpenses:Expenses
    @Binding var totalExpenses: Double
    @State var selectedExpenseItem:Expense? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {
                List {
                    ForEach(myExpenses.items) { item in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(item.name)")
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                self.selectedExpenseItem = item
                            } ) {
                                Text("View")
                            }
                        }
                        .deleteDisabled(item.isDeletable)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: removeItem)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Total Expenses:")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(myExpenses.totalExpenses(), specifier: "%.2f")")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Expenses")
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    let newExpense = Expense(name: "Enter name", type: "Expense item", cost: 10.00, isDeletable: false)
                    self.myExpenses.items.append(newExpense)
                    self.totalExpenses = myExpenses.totalExpenses()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
            }
        .fullScreenCover(item: $selectedExpenseItem) { myItem in
            ItemDetailView(item: myItem, myExpenses: myExpenses, totalExpenses: $totalExpenses)
        }
    }
    func removeItem(at offsets: IndexSet){
        self.myExpenses.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        self.totalExpenses = myExpenses.totalExpenses()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just noting that I'm using the `NestedObservableObject` approach from @bsorrentino in my latest app.

Normally I'd avoid this but the nested object in question is actually a CoreData model so breaking things out into smaller views doesn't really work in this regard.

This solution seemed best since the world treats NSManagedObjects as (mostly) ObservableObjects and I really, really need to trigger an update if the CodeData object model is changed down the line.

Answer (score -1):

The var submodel in AppModel doesn't need the property wrapper @Published.
The purpose of @Published is to emit new values and objectWillChange.
But the variable is never changed but only initiated once.

Changes in submodel are propagated to the view by the subscriber anyCancellable and ObservableObject-protocol via the sink-objectWillChange construction and causes a View to redraw.

```
class SubModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    let submodel = SubModel()
    
    var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    init() {
        anyCancellable = submodel.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] (_) in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nested `ObservableObject` models do not work yet.

However, you can make it work by manually subscribing each model. [The answer gave a simple example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58406402/826435).

I wanted to add that you can make this manual process a bit more streamlined & readable via extensions:

```
class Submodel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0
}

class AppModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var submodel = Submodel()
  @Published var submodel2 = Submodel2() // the code for this is not defined and is for example only
  private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

  init() {
    // subscribe to changes in `Submodel`
    submodel
      .subscribe(self)
      .store(in: &cancellables)

    // you can also subscribe to other models easily (this solution scales well):
    submodel2
      .subscribe(self)
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

Here is the extension:

```
extension ObservableObject where Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher  {

  func subscribe<T: ObservableObject>(
    _ observableObject: T
  ) -> AnyCancellable where T.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher {
    return objectWillChange
      // Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed.
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .sink { [weak observableObject] (_) in
        observableObject?.objectWillChange.send()
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

It looks like bug. When I update the xcode to the latest version, it work correctly when binding to nested ObservableObjects

Comment: Can you clarify what xcode version you are currently on that works? I currently have Xcode 11.0 and experience this issue. I've had trouble getting upgrading to 11.1, it won't get past like 80% complete.