# How to tell SwiftUI views to bind to more than one nested ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have two classes nested in another class, which is an observable object in a SwiftUI view. Even though properties in the nested classes are declared as @Published, their values (when they change) do not update in the main view.

A similar question has been asked here, and I could use it to get it to work for one of the two subclasses, but not both.

[How to tell SwiftUI views to bind to nested ObservableObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406287/how-to-tell-swiftui-views-to-bind-to-nested-observableobjects)

This is the model:

```
class Submodel1: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0
}

class Submodel2: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
  @Published var submodel1: Submodel1 = Submodel1()
  @Published var submodel2: Submodel2 = Submodel2()
}
```

And this is the main view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model: Model = Model()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Count: \(model.submodel1.count)")
        .onTapGesture {
          self.model.submodel1.count += 1
        }
      Text("Count: \(model.submodel2.count)")
        .onTapGesture {
          self.model.submodel2.count += 1
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding this to the model class (see previous Stackoverflow question) works for updating on submodel1 changes, but not both:

```
  var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
  init() {
      anyCancellable = submodel1.objectWillChange.sink { (_) in
          self.objectWillChange.send()
      }
   }
```

What I'm looking for is some way to pass on changes of both the submodel1 and submodel2 to my view.

Comment: I have justed posted an alternative solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63291258/1837715). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can expand upon the answer in the question you linked to by using [`CombineLatest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/combinelatest) to have your model fire its `objectWillChange` publisher when either of the underlying objects change:

```
import Combine

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var submodel1: Submodel1 = Submodel1()
    @Published var submodel2: Submodel2 = Submodel2()

    var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

    init() {
        anyCancellable = Publishers.CombineLatest(submodel1.$count,submodel2.$count).sink(receiveValue: {_ in
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, I was using the view modifier `onReceive` block with the publisher to update a state variable and then used that used that state variable in the view body.

Comment: combine latest seems to have a maximum of 4 objects? What if we have more than 4 objects?

Comment: I'd like to second Marwan's Question: what if I have more objects than Publishers.CombineLatest4 can handle? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/combinelatest4

Comment: Now that I have more experience with combine and SwiftUI I probably wouldn't use this approach. I would create a `ViewModel` that used the `Model` to expose and handle updates to the relevant properties. The view model subscribes to the properties in the model and exposes new published properties.

Comment: Just wanted to take a moment to appreciate how this answer saved my day. My last three days, actually. It was driving me mad, I could not find a workaround to the problem. Thx.