# SwiftUI - YAPPNU (Yet Another @Published Property Not Updating)

Tags: swiftui, publishing

In the code below, part of a crossword app, I have created a **Grid**, which contains **squares**, an @Published array of Squares, and a GridView to display an instance of Grid, **griddy**. When I change griddy's squares in the GridView, the GridView gets recreated, as expected, and I see an "!" instead of an "A".

Now I've added one more level -- a **Puzzle** contains an @Published Grid, **griddy**. In PuzzleView, I therefore work with puzzle.griddy. This doesn't work, though. The letter doesn't change, and a break point in PuzzleView's body never gets hit.

Why? I'm working on an app where I really need these 3 distinct structures.

```
import SwiftUI


class Square : ObservableObject {
    @Published var letter: String
    
    init(letter: String){
        self.letter = letter
    }
}

class Grid : ObservableObject {
    @Published var squares:[[Square]] = [
        [Square(letter: "A"), Square(letter: "B"), Square(letter: "C")],
        [Square(letter: "D"), Square(letter: "E"), Square(letter: "F"), ]
    ]
    
}

class Puzzle: ObservableObject {
    @Published var griddy: Grid = Grid()
}

struct GridView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var griddy: Grid
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(griddy.squares[0][0].letter)")
            Button("Change Numbers"){
                griddy.squares[0][0] = Square(letter:"!")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PuzzleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var puzzle: Puzzle
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(puzzle.griddy.squares[0][0].letter)")
            Button("Change Numbers"){
                puzzle.griddy.squares[0][0] = Square(letter:"!")
            }
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        // PuzzleView().environmentObject(Puzzle())
        GridView().environmentObject(Grid())
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a slightly different question, but my answer would be the same as there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62988407/968155. The simplest solution is to make `Square`  a value-type: `struct Square { var letter: String }` (no need for `@Published` or `ObservableObject`)

Comment: I need Square to be an ObservableObject -- it's observed in a SquareView -- so I need it to be a class. But thanks for your response and the idea.

Comment: to be "observed" it doesn't need to be an `ObservableObject` - there are paradigms, like `Bindings` to pass values between views. It would makes sense for it to be an observable object if it had its own lifecycle events (e.g. value is updated based on some external trigger). In any case, the other answer tells you how to deal with `ObservableObject`s (the last approach mentioned there)

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could just add this to your `Puzzle` object:

```
var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

init() {
    self.anyCancellable = griddy.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: {
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    })
}
```

It's a trick I found in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58440744/11161266), it'll cause changes in the child object to trigger the parent's `objectWillChange`.

#### Edit:

I would like to note that if you change the child object:

```
puzzle.griddy = someOtherGriddyObject
```

then you will still be subscribed to the changes of the *old* `griddy` object, and you won't receive new updates.

You can *probably* get by this by just updating the cancellable after changing the object:

```
puzzle.griddy = someOtherGriddyObject
puzzle.anyCancellable = puzzle.griddy.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: {
        puzzle.objectWillChange.send()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Think in this direction: in MVVM SwiftUI concept every introduced `ObservableObject` entity must be paired with corresponding view `ObservedObject` (`EnvironmentObject` is the same as `ObservedObject`, just with different injection mechanism), so specific change in *ViewModel* would refresh corresponding *View*, there is no other *magic/automatic* propagations of changes from model to view.

So if `Square` is `ObservableObject`, there should be some `SquareView`, as

```
struct SquareView {
   @ObservedObject var vm: Square
   ...
```

so if you `Puzzle` observable includes `Grid` observable, then corresponding `PuzzleView` having observed puzzle should include `GridView` having observed grid, which should include `SqareView` having observed square.

Ie.

```
struct PuzzleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var puzzle: Puzzle
    
    var body: some View {
       GridView().environmentObject(puzzle.griddy)
    }
}

// ... and same for GridView, and so on...
```

This approach result in very optimal update, because modifying one Square makes only one corresponding SquareView refreshed.

**But if you accumulate all *Squares.objectWillChange* in one container update, then modifying one Square result in total UI update, that is bad and for UI fluency and for battery.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd say because Grid is reference type, and `@Published` is triggered when `griddy` is mutated.

```
class Puzzle: ObservableObject {
    @Published var griddy: Grid = Grid()
}
```

Note that `griddy` does not actually mutate since it is a reference.

But why does it work in `@EnvironmentObject var griddy: Grid`?

My guess is that SDK implicitly observes publishers in an `@ObservableObject`.

But maybe someone can provide better detail answer.

I personally would avoid long publisher chain, and just flatten the nested structure.