# Correct way to call an ObservableObject in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have the following class:

```
final class NetworkController: ObservableObject {
    
    init() {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            print("⚠️ Inside init")
            Task(priority: .medium){
                await configureAmplify()
                await checkUserSignedIn()
            }
        } else {
            print(" Failed to Initialize Amplify")
        }
    }
    
    
    @Published var authState: AuthState = .guess    // Observes state changes in the session

...

}
```

If I try to initialize it to access some function inside, like this:

final class DataStorePersistanceHandler: ObservableObject {

```
var networkController = NetworkController()

...
```

}

I get the `NetworkController` class looping multiple times, my guess is that it's recreating the view and therefore calling it multiple times, so my question is, how can I initialize it without doing so? I just want to have it initialized for when I need it.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a school thing? I'm having Deja Vu here. Every time you call `NetworkController()` you are creating a different instance. One does not know what the other is doing. Make `NetworkController` a singleton or share the original instance some how.

Comment: lool no no a school thing. `NetworkController`'s instance is being shared in the environment with `@StateObject` and `.environmentObject` is that what you mean?

Comment: see if this answer your question regarding nesting ObservableObjects.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437861/how-to-tell-swiftui-views-to-bind-to-more-than-one-nested-observableobject

Comment: @workingdog no it doesn't, so the question is, how do I call in a class an existing `ObservableObject` class just to reference it

Comment: can you show where and how you are calling these or at least DataStorePersistanceHandler.

Comment: "NetworkController's instance is being shared in the environment with @StateObject and .environmentObject is that what you mean?" You have not posted code that shows this, and the only code you have posted, your `DataStorePersistanceHandler{}` specifically does NOT use a singleton, but initializes a new instance.