# Pass data between view models in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mvvm

I have a parent view and a child view. Both the parent and child view have their own view model. In the child view, the user can make a selection which is saved in a `[String]`. I want to use the values from the child view's `[String]` in the parent view. What would the best way be to go about passing the data between the view models and thus the views?

I would prefer not to use an environment object, as these values will only be used in these two views.

Here are the view models as an example.

```
class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedExercise = [String]()
}
```

```
class ChildViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedExercise = [String]()
}
```

Comment: Too little information really but do you need two view models? What about passing the array to the child view as a Binding?

Comment: Either as suggested above, have a `@Binding` in child view, or if you have to have 2 view models for other reasons, you can for example keep `selectedExercise` in a child view model, and keep an instance of the `ChildViewModel` in the `ParentViewModel`, so when oyu load the child, you pass that instance from the parent, and parent uses `selectedExercise` from that same model

Comment: Note, it is not a good idea to **nest** ObservableObjects.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine official source of that claim please? yes, nested observables can be tricky, but "not a good idea" is an overreaction. Really depends on the use

Comment: This is just my opinion that it is not a good idea, especially now that we have [Observation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Observation).
I based my opinion from these SO posts dealing with nested ObservableObjects, [nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406287/how-to-tell-swiftui-views-to-bind-to-nested-observableobjects), [nested observable](https://rhonabwy.com/2021/02/13/nested-observable-objects-in-swiftui/), [is it ok to nest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824472/swiftui-is-it-ok-to-put-an-observableobject-inside-another-observableobject)

Comment: Move shared data down to a manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI the View struct holds the view data already so there is no need for any objects and it's just:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var selectedExercise = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        // read only
        ReadOnlyChildView(selectedExercise: selectedExercise) // or transform the selection via a computed property

        // or if you need read/write
        ReadWriteChildView(selectedExercise: $selectedExercise)
    }
}
```

and

```
struct ReadOnlyChildView: View {
   // read only 
   let selectedExercise: [String]

    var body: some View {
         // called when selectedExcercise value changes from last time this View was init
        ...
    }
}

struct ReadWriteChildView: View {
   // If read/write needed
   @Binding var selectedExercise: [String]  

   ...
}
```

If you do attempt to use objects instead of learning how the View structs work then you'll basically be re-implementing SwiftUI which is a complete waste of time!