# Trying to Bind an ObservableObject but getting Cannot assign to property: 'XXXX' is a get-only property Error

Tags: binding, swiftui, observableobject

I am quite new in Swift and SwiftUI and I am getting a error that I cannot understand.

Here is my class that I load with JSON from a web service

```
class ResaListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var resasDeparts = [ResaViewModel]()
    
    init() {
        WSResa().getDeparts { resas in
            if let resas = resas as? [Resa] {
                self.resasDeparts = resas.map(ResaViewModel.init)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ResaViewModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var resa: Resa
    
    init(resa: Resa) {
        self.resa = resa
    }
    
    var id: Int {
        return Int(self.resa.id)!
    }

 var nbveh: Int
    {
        return Int(self.resa.nbveh) ?? 0
    }
}
```

In a view I would like to Bind the nbveh property and to increment and decrement it with buttons.

the error is : **"Cannot assign to property: 'nbveh' is a get-only property"**

```
struct ResaDetail: View {
    @ObservedObject var resa:ResaViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
      vehiculeView(nbveh: $resa.nbveh)
}

struct ResaView: View {
    let resaListVM = ResaListViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List(self.resaListVM.resasDeparts, id: \.id) { resa in
            NavigationLink(destination: ResaDetail(resa: resa)) {
                ResaList(resa: resa)
            }
        }
    } .navigationBarTitle(Text("Réservations"))
}
```

How can I make this property editable and bindable ?

Thanks for any kind of help

--
Godefroy

Answer (score 1):

And the answer to send the message when it is changed and to reload the UI is :

```
get { return Int(resa.nbveh) ?? 0 }
    set { resa.nbveh = String(newValue)
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `nbveh` property in your `ResaViewModel` is a [computed property](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-computed-property). A `Binding` in SwiftUI needs to be able set and get the value. Because of the way computed properties work, you can only `get` them, and not `set` them.

The solution would be to change the `nbveh` to this:

```
var nbveh: Int {
    get { return Int(resa.nbveh) ?? 0 }
    set { resa.nbveh = newValue }
}
```

This tells Swift to execute the code in `get { }` whenever you're reading the value, and it will execute `set { }` when setting `nbveh`.
This way you'll be able to it as a `Binding`.

A different solution could be to get rid of your `nbveh` var in your `ResaViewModel` and simply use the `nbveh` property of `resa` in `ResaViewModel`. This would look like this:

```
vehiculeView(nbveh: $resa.resa.nbveh)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I have tried both options. And with the get and set the problem is that if update the value it does not update the view. I should probably add an objectWillChange somewhere. I tried to add the property @Published to the nbveh attribute, but it does not apply on computed value. The second option work but feels like the resaViewModel become useless

Comment: I can see that you have nested `ObservableObject`s, which is not supported yet, that could be part of your problem why your view does not update. See here for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406287/how-to-tell-swiftui-views-to-bind-to-nested-observableobjects

Comment: I, I found the solution by adding when I set the object attribute objectWillChange.send()