# SwiftUI can't bind class array parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, uiviewrepresentable

In my `SwiftUI` project I have a button `class` model:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Button: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var title = String()

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
    
    func changeTitle(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Then I have another `class` named `ControlPanel` which has as a parameter a Button array.

```
class ControlPanel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var name = String()
    @Published var buttons:[Button] = []
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }  
}
```

I have to listen to this array in a custom collection view I have built with a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` class:

```
struct ButtonCollectionView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var buttons: [Button]
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UICollectionViewController {
        let vc = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: .init())
        vc.buttonArray = buttons
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UICollectionViewController, context: Context) {
        if let vc = uiViewController as? CollectionViewController {
            vc.buttonArray = buttons
            vc.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, I call for this collection view in my content view, the following way:

```
@ObservedObject var controlPanel: ControlPanel = ControlPanel(name: "test")

var body: some View {
    ButtonCollectionView(button: $controlPanel.buttons)
}
```

When I load my content view I do get all the cells, but once I change them, the view won't get updated. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Button` is already inside another `@Published` property and thus `@Published var title` won't work.

The simplest solution is to make your `Button` a *struct* (and rename it to something not used by SwiftUI, eg. `CustomButton`):

```
struct CustomButton: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title = ""
    
    mutating func changeTitle(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

For more advanced solutions see: [How to tell SwiftUI views to bind to nested ObservableObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406287/how-to-tell-swiftui-views-to-bind-to-nested-observableobjects)