# SwiftUI view is not updating from environmentObject observable property

Tags: swiftui, environmentobject

I'm connecting a firestore database to my UI.

I've created an SignedInAuthentication object which I set as an environment object

```
class SignedInAuthentication: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User
    @Published var workoutCompletionStore: WorkoutCompletionDataStoreProtocol

    init(user: User, workoutCompletionStore: WorkoutCompletionDataStoreProtocol) {
        self.user = user
        self.workoutCompletionStore = workoutCompletionStore
    }

    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        workoutCompletionStore = WorkoutCompletionDataStore(userId: user.userId)
    }
}
```

the WorkoutCOmpletionStore is implemented as follow:

```
class WorkoutCompletionDataStore: ObservableObject, WorkoutCompletionDataStoreProtocol {
    @Published var workoutCompletions: [WorkoutCompletion] = []
    private let userId: String?
 
    [...]

 func get() {
        guard let userId = userId
        else {
            workoutCompletions = []
            return
        }

        let fullPath = String(format: path, userId)
        store.collection(fullPath)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    AnalyticsWrapper.logError(message: "Error getting worKoutCompletions", error: error)
                    return
                }

                self.workoutCompletions = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { document in
                    try? document.data(as: WorkoutCompletion.self)
                } ?? []
            }
    }
[...]
}
```

The snapshot listener is called as expected. the list of workoutCompletion is updated (I'm removing and adding objects).

The problem I have is that the view that displays those workoutCompletion does not update after the WorkoutCompletionDataStore update its workoutCompletions when Firstore update fires.

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var homeQueryData: HomeQueryData
    @AppStorage("didShowOnboarding") var didShowOnboarding: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var signedInAuthentication: SignedInAuthentication


    func startChat() {
        let controller = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first?.rootViewController
        Freshchat.sharedInstance().showConversations(controller!)
    }

    var body: some View {
        var workoutCompletions = signedInAuthentication.workoutCompletionStore.workoutCompletions
    [...]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The issue you have is often due to nesting ObservableObjects as you do.
IMHO the best thing to do, is to restructure your code and have separate 
 ObservableObjects. Things would work then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI View updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710726/swiftui-view-updating)

Comment: @workingdog if you enter this as an answer, i'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: your answer will do, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @workingdog, I refactor my code so that WorkoutCompletionDataStore is a top level environment object and it is now working.

Nesting Observable object does not seem to work.