# ObservedRealmObject not invalidating View when Object property is mutated

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have not worked extensively with RealmSwift before, so perhaps the solution to my issue may be quite trivial. I have been attempting to configure the `GroupView` below such that it reflects the state of its `group` ObservedObject. Note that the view binds to `photo._url` in the AsyncImage initializer in the aim of reevaluating the view when the photo's url is modified.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct GroupView: View {
    @Environment(\.realmUser) var user //custom environment key
    @ObservedRealmObject var group: Group
    var body: some View {
            HStack(spacing: 20){
                ForEach((group.groupContent?.tableContent?.photos)!,id: \.id){ photo in
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: photo._url)){ phase in
                        switch phase{
                        case .success(let image):
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        case .failure:
                            Text("Image not found").task {
                                 if let user = user{
                                    await photo.refreshURLIfNeeded(user: user)
                                }
                            }
                        case .empty:
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                    }.task{
                        if let user = user{
                            let _ = await photo.refreshURLIfNeeded(user:user)
                        }
                       
                      }
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```

The problem occurs as the AsyncImageView is not being reevaluated even after the `_url` property of a photo in the *group.groupContents?.tableContent?.photos* EmbeddedObject is updated by the call to `photo.refreshPhotoURL(user:User)` (I have verified the urls are being updated with valid photo links in the Atlas Console, so an empty/invalid url is not the culprit). Since the binding, `$group`, is not directly available in the body of refreshPhotoURL, the update is performed through the realm!.write{} transaction after thawing, following realm's examples for [performing an explicit write](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/write/#perform-an-explicit-write).

```swift
extension Photo{
func refreshURLIfNeeded(user: User) async{
//Call serverless Atlas function for new URL
   let urlString = try? await user.functions.refreshURL([AnyBSON(self.id!)]).stringValue
    
let realm = self.realm!.thaw()
        try! realm.write{
            self.thaw()!._url = urlString ?? ""
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

```swift
final class Group: Object,ObjectKeyIdentifiable{
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var groupContent: GroupContent?
}

final class GroupContent: EmbeddedObject{
    @Persisted var tableContent: TableContent?
}

final class tableContent:EmbeddedObject{ 
    @Persisted var photos: List<Photo>
}
```

Changing the `_url` property manually in Atlas Console also elicits in no response/invalidation in an active `GroupView`. What could be causing the AsyncImageViews to remain unchanged even after modifying the value of an embedded property in the observed `group`?

### EDIT:

The issue does not appear to be linked to the embedding, as setting `TableContent` to be an Object instead of an EmbeddedObject and passing it into the GroupView in place of `group` still results in the view not updating.

Comment: You likely need to create a "row view" and use the object wrapper for each photo

Comment: I've extracted the AsyncImage into its own subview with photo wrapped as an `@ObservedRealmObject`, and changed the Photo class to conform `ObjectKeyIdentifiable`, and the individual Photo views invalidated upon changes to the 'photo.url property'. Does this mean that only top-level properties (within an Object or EmbeddedObject) push change notifications to the View(s) which observe them?

Comment: No, properties in Lists also fire events. Note there are a number of places where the code could be going wrong, but would silently fail. Did you add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so where was that - which line did not resolve as expected? Is this message displaying *"Image not found"*? Also, did you (as a test) attempt to thaw the photo before the write transaction?

Comment: Yes, realm uses ObservableObject (along with other things) to make their wrappers work so every object needs a wrapper so you can see changes.

Comment: @Jay I set breakpoints on the code above and discovered that the body, or even the AsyncImage within that body, were *not* be reevaluated as the model was changing. However, after changing Photo to conform to `ObjectKeyIdentifiable` and creating a subview containing each Photo (per suggestion of @lorem-ipsum) as an `@ObservedRealmObject`, the breakpoints would fire *and* the AsyncImage was refreshed with the new url, resolving the issue.

Comment: Excellent! That sounds like an answer that may be helpful to others. May be a good idea to post it. [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my edited question, the matter of instances being either top-level `Objects` or `EmbeddedObject`s had less to do with the root cause of the issue. Rather, the problem faced above was rooted in the implementation of the `@ObservedRealmObject` [property wrapper in RealmSwift](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/blob/330a239712af77a3b0926b9ffa9582302a0b9923/RealmSwift/SwiftUI.swift#L994-L1079), which itself relies upon SwiftUI's `@ObservedObject` property wrapper in order to deliver its persisting/invalidating functionality.

To capture the problem that is occurring with the `@ObservedRealmObject`, I have produced the following example containing nested ObservableObjects:

#### @ObservedObject Behavior (Swift 5.8 & SwiftUI 4.0)

```
 class ObserveMe:ObservableObject{
    @Published var observeMeOnceMore = ObserveMeOnceMore() 
}
class ObserveMeOnceMore:ObservableObject{
    @Published var counter = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var observeMe = ObserveMe()
    var body: some View {
       
            Button("Does not publish: \(observeMe.observeMeOnceMore.counter)"){
                observeMe.observeMeOnceMore.counter += 1 //Change not published to view since observation does not occur at the level of @ObserveMeOnceMore
                print(observeMe.observeMeOnceMore.counter)
            }
        CounterView(observeMeOnceMore: observeMe.observeMeOnceMore)
        
    }
}

struct CounterView:View{
    @ObservedObject var observeMeOnceMore: ObserveMeOnceMore
    var body:some View{
        Button("Does publish: \(observeMeOnceMore.counter)"){
            observeMeOnceMore.counter += 1
            print(observeMeOnceMore.counter) //Works as expected
        }
    }
}
```

In the course of writing this answer, I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68713038/12783209) by @lorem-ipsum, which appears to reflect the common issue of an inappropriate *level* of observation occurring in `Views` containning ObservableObject instances.

Applying the observation-level principles of `@ObservedObject` to `@ObservedRealmObject`, creating a separate `PhotoView` which accepts `EmbeddedObject`s directly as parameters allowed for the precise *level* of observation that the GroupView required. The only tricky detail is that the EmbeddedObject (or Object) must conform to `ObjectKeyIdentifiable` in order to be bindable by the `@ObservedRealmObject` property wrapper (the compiler warning, `No exact matches in call to initializer`. I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/8355) to improve the compiler warning, but it is not a major issue for the time being.

Comment: Good explanation, just a tidbit Apple "fixes" this issue in iOS 17 with `@Observable` I suspect that MongoDB/Realm will be updating their implementation. `ObservableObject`s have no place in iOS 17+