# Calling objectWillChange.send() produce performance issues

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, core-data

I have a project with a nested object structure

`Project -> Panels -> Layers`

and I have SettingsView where I update different properties of any of these structures.

On every update I have to call `objectWillChange.send()` to see changes in View immediately.
If I have a small number of objects it works fine and produces no performance issues. But if the number of objects increases it makes perf issues.

Example of my code below:

```swift
class SelectedProjectHolder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var projects: [Project] = []
    @Published var selectedProject: Project? = nil
.....
    func updateTextLayerColor(for textLayer: TextLayer, newColor: Color) {
        guard let selectedProject = selectedProject else {
            return
        }
        
        for (panelIndex, panel) in selectedProject.panels.enumerated() {
            if let layerIndex = panel.textLayers.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == textLayer.id }) {
                selectedProject.panels[panelIndex].textLayers[layerIndex].color = newColor
                objectWillChange.send()
                return
            }
        }
    }
....
}

struct MainApp: App {
    
    let selectedProjectHolder = SelectedProjectHolder()
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(lastSaveTime: lastSaveTime)
                .environmentObject(selectedProjectHolder)
        }
        .commands {
            SidebarCommands()
        }
    }
}

// example of Panel view with passed data:
struct PanelView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var selectedProjectHolder: SelectedProjectHolder
    @Binding var panel: Panel
...
}
```

What do I miss and why it doesn't work without calling `objectWillChange.send()` explicitly?

Is there a way to see changes immediately without calling `objectWillChange.send()` whenever I make changes in `selectedProject` property of `SelectedProjectHolder`?

Comment: Project should be  struct and you also need a StateObject

Comment: This is purely speculative because you haven't included some of the most important parts to diagnose this (`Project` definition and how you observe the `SelectedProjectHelper` in the `View` you expect to update), but I'm guessing one or both of: 1) `Project` is a `class` 2) You aren't actually using `@EnvironmentObject` in your `View`

Comment: Yes, Project is a class, although now I'm trying to convert it to the struct. Does having it as a class doesn't allow view to show updated state of `@Binding var`?

P.S. I've added a bit of PanelView definition, if it helps

Comment: If it is a class, you will have to call send manually. If your data structure is all structs, it will happen automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710726/swiftui-view-updating/68713038#68713038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not structured correctly. The object should only hold the projects and should be responsible for loading and saving. The selected project should be `@State` in a ProjectsView. Or state in a common parent with @Binding passed to a child View that can change the selection and passed as let to a child View that just reads the current selection.

Make a computed property that transforms the selection into a colour and pass that into a child View init. Body will be called when a different colour is passed in. No need for objects or objectWillChange, this basic change detection is already built into SwiftUI View structs.

Example code:

```
struct ProjectsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var projectsStore: ProjectsStore
    @State var selectedProject: Project? = nil

    // transform from the selection to the color
    // this is called every time the selection changes
    var textLayerColor: Color {
        guard let selectedProject = selectedProject else {
            return defaultColor
        }
        ...
        // find the color you want
        ...
        return newColor
    }

    var body: View {
    ...
        ForEach(projectsStore.projects) { project in
            // pass computed property into child View
            PanelView(color: textLayerColor) 
        ...
```

Comment: thanks for responding! I'm trying to wrap my head around it. As I understand, I still can use @Binding. But I don't get of why view doesn't show an updated view, unless I call `objectWillChange.send()`?

P.S. I've added a bit of PanelView definition, if it helps

Comment: As I said the code is not structured correctly so you have some kind of hack to make it work. Better to structure it correctly as in my answer, let me know if you need example code.

Comment: Yes, an example would be awesome, please share!

Comment: ok added an example of how to use state for selection and use computed property to transform data