# How can I make a button add a textfield if you press it in the same page view?

Tags: button, swiftui

I'm having a problem coding this view so I want to be able to press the plus button then add another exercise in the same page.

[image: here here]
[image]

I used this code but is says( Result of 'VStack<Content>' initializer is unused)

```swift
Button(action: {
   
    VStack{
     HStack {
      Text("Exercise Name").bold()
      TextField("EX: Narrow Stance Leg Press", text: .constant("")).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
     }
     ZStack{
    
      HStack {
    Spacer()
    Picker("Number of Sets", selection: $selectedNumber){
     ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { number in
      Text("\(number)")
      
     }
    }.frame(width: 102.0, height: 25.0)
      }
      HStack {
    
    Text("Number of sets:").bold()
    Spacer()
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).stroke(.gray).frame(width: 133,height: 25)
      }
     }
     
     ZStack{
    
      HStack {
    Spacer()
    Picker("Number of reps", selection: $selectedNumber2){
     ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { number in
      Text("\(number)")
      
     }
    }.frame(width: 102.0, height: 25.0)
      }
      HStack {
    
    Text("Number of reps:").bold()
    Spacer()
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).stroke(.gray).frame(width: 133,height: 25)
      }
     }

    }
    
   }) {
    ZStack{
     Text("+").bold()
     RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).stroke(.gray).frame(width: 133,height: 25)
    }
```

As I said, I want to press the plus then the same block (exercise name, # of sets, # of reps) adds again for the user to add another exercise.

Comment: You have view code inside the action which is a Void you have to take it out of the Void and into a View

Comment: oh okay ,but there is already the same block outside the button but what I meant is when I press the button I want to add the same block again in the same page is this possible? or do I need another page to do that?

Comment: You’ll need an Array of some kind and a ForEach so the code can repeat with the new data. Append the object to the array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710726/swiftui-view-updating/68713038#68713038

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `struct` to hold the data so you can update, and an `Array` so you create as many items as you want here the example:

```
import SwiftUI


    struct Exercise: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        var name: String = ""
        var sets: Int = 1
        var rep: Int = 1
        
    }

    struct ExerciseView: View {
        
        @State private var exercises: [Exercise] = [Exercise()]
        
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack {
                
                ForEach($exercises) { $item in
                    ExerciseDetailView(exercise: $item)}
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button("+") {
                    exercises.append(Exercise())
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }


    struct ExerciseDetailView: View {
        
        @Binding var exercise: Exercise
        
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    Text("Exercise Name").bold()
                    TextField("EX: Narrow Stance Leg Press", text: $exercise.name).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                }
                ZStack{
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Picker("Number of Sets", selection: $exercise.sets){
                            ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { number in
                                Text("\(number)")
                                
                            }
                        }.frame(width: 102.0, height: 25.0)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        
                        Text("Number of sets:").bold()
                        Spacer()
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).stroke(.gray).frame(width: 133,height: 25)
                    }
                }
                
                ZStack{
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Picker("Number of reps", selection: $exercise.rep){
                            ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { number in
                                Text("\(number)")
                                
                            }
                        }.frame(width: 102.0, height: 25.0)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        
                        Text("Number of reps:").bold()
                        Spacer()
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).stroke(.gray).frame(width: 133,height: 25)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]