List view not updating in a MVVM scenario
I created a small sample for demonstrating the issue. I have a class ItemContent which is a container for rows of type ContentRow.
The ContentView shows a simple list of editable RowViews and the add new row function is handled within the ViewModel.
For some reason the list is not updated when adding rows. I tested several combinations of state wrappers but couldn’t figure out how to update UI from the updated vm.itemContent.children. So I’m clearly missing something here.
class ItemContent: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    //container for content rows/ content tree.
    
    @Published var id = UUID()
    @Published var children: [ContentRow] = []
}

class ContentRow: Identifiable, Hashable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var id = UUID()
    @Published var title = "new"
    @Published var children: [ContentRow] = []
    
    static func ==(lhs: ContentRow, rhs: ContentRow) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

//MARK: - views/ view model.

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(selection: $vm.selectedRows) {
                ForEach(vm.itemContent.children, id: \.id) { row in
                    RowView(row: row)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button("add", action: vm.add)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct RowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var row: ContentRow
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("editable text", text: $row.title)
            Text(row.id.uuidString)
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var itemContent = ItemContent()
        @Published var selectedRows = Set<ContentRow>()
        
        func add() {
            let row = ContentRow()
            itemContent.children.append(row)
        }
    }
}

I also tried the solution here but id didn’t help. 1

Add ObservableObject to ContentView, add Published to the properties and remove the custom Hashable and Equatable. Then get rid of all the Binding row code and use ObservedObject

Thanks. Did you really mean “add ObservableObject to ContentView”? Not sure I’m getting the point here.

Row sorry not view

Thanks. I can’t remove Hashable and Equatable because of  using Set for the list selection.I updated ContentRow with Observable and Publish as I changed the Binding to ObservedObject in the RowView. But it still does not update the list.

Then include all the properties not just the id. SwiftUI uses it, it quite literally tells SwiftUI to only render when the id changes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710726/swiftui-view-updating/68713038#68713038

Item content need to be observed too look at the link.

Note that if you migrate to Observable all these layers aren’t needed.

I added the updated code as I understood your comments and the comments in the mentioned post, but it is still not updating the list.

You still aren’t observing item content and you haven’t adjusted the custom protocol implementations

You don't need to set all the models as ObservableObjecs. Your view model will be the one that is observable and will notify changes to the view for the properties marked as @Published.
In your particular case you just need to define your models as simple value types using structs and that will fix the issue.
struct ItemContent {
    var id = UUID()
    var children: [ContentRow] = []
}

struct ContentRow: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title = "new"
    var children: [ContentRow] = []
}

There's no need to set ItemContent as Identifiable either since the values passed to the list are of type ContentRow.
Updated answer
In order to fix the items addition issue just change the models to be value types. And regarding the selection topic just use the List component initialiser like this:
List($vm.itemContent.children, id: \.self, selection: $vm.selectedRows) {
    RowView(row: $row)
}

And add an EditButton to support editing mode:
.toolbar {
    ...
    EditButton()
}


Hi po24, thanks. Yes the structs are working here. But how should I implement list selection using Set when using only structs. The compiler tells me to use a class which needs to be hashable. The Identifiable was accidentally copied from my project where it’s needed.

Regarding the selection issue you are not correctly using the List component api. Just set it to be like this:
List($vm.itemContent.children, id: \.self, selection: $vm.selectedRows) { RowView(row: $row) }
And you are good to go

you should not have ItemContent with @Published, this is wrong.

Totally true, it was a copy-paste issue. Just updated the answer.

Try this approach making structs instead of classes for ItemContent and ContentRow.
Works well for me, adding new rows is displayed in the list.
Tested on real iOS-18 device, MacCatalyst and MacOS 15.
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {  // <--- here
    @Published var itemContent = ItemContent()
    @Published var selectedRows = Set<ContentRow>()
    
    func add() {
        let row = ContentRow()
        itemContent.children.append(row)
    }
}

struct ItemContent: Identifiable, Hashable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var children: [ContentRow] = []
}

struct ContentRow: Identifiable, Hashable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var title = "new"
    var children: [ContentRow] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(selection: $vm.selectedRows) {
                ForEach($vm.itemContent.children) { $row in  // <--- here
                    RowView(row: $row)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button("add", action: vm.add)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    @Binding var row: ContentRow
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("editable text", text: $row.title)
            Text(row.id.uuidString)
        }
    }
}

For more info, see also Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.
I also recommend using the newer framework Observation, see Managing model data in your app

Thanks workingdog for the Apple links.
