# @ObservedObject or @Published

Tags: swiftui, combine

In swiftui, I have a presenter here,

```
class Presenter {

     @Published private(set) var viewModel: ContentViewModel

     @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: ContentViewModel
}
```

ContentViewModel conforms ObservableObject.

Which one is correct? Why?

Answer (score 1):

First, it's likely that `Presenter`  should be annotated as `ObservableObject`:

```
class Presenter : ObservableObject {
```

Secondly, when using a `class` like you say that `ContentViewModel` is, neither `Published` or `ObservedObject` is likely to have the effect that you're expecting.

In a `View`, `@ObservedObject` lets the `View` know to watch for updates to the `@Published` properties of an `ObservableObject`. When its `objectWillChange` publisher emits a new value, the `View` is re-rendered. But, your `Presenter` is not a `View`, so that's not applicable here.

`@Published` is used on an `ObservableObject` to create a publisher that will signal a `View` (see above paragraph). With value types (ie `structs`), the updates are sent automatically when the value changes. But, you're trying to use it on a reference type (a `class`), so updates won't get published automatically. Instead, you'll have to call `objectWillChange` manually when you update the object. See [How to tell SwiftUI views to bind to nested ObservableObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406287/how-to-tell-swiftui-views-to-bind-to-nested-observableobjects) for more information on this and different strategies.

Without knowing how you'll use the `Presenter` it's hard to give advice about what path to take going forward.

Comment: Did this answer your question?