# Subview Not triggering disable state update in parent view SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a couple of nested views with nested viewModels that I need to ensure validation on.

Essentially ViewA has a form a Submit button and a Subview (ViewB) - the ViewModel for ViewB is contained within ViewB **This architecture  cannot change due to boring business reasons** ViewB has some form fields. I need to ensure all the fields are valid in ViewA and ViewB before the Submit button is enabled.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this as any of the changes in ViewB are not triggering a refresh of ViewA

Here's some simplified code as a rough example

```
    class ViewModelB: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    @Published var textTwo = ""
    
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        !text.isEmpty && !textTwo.isEmpty
    }
}

class ViewModelA: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    @ObservedObject var addressViewModel: ViewModelB = ViewModelB()

    func isValid() -> Bool {
        print("is Valid called")
        return !text.isEmpty && addressViewModel.isValid()
    }
}
struct AddressView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModelB

    init(addressModel:ViewModelB) {
        self.viewModel = addressModel
    }
    var body: some View {
        TextField("View B Text", text: $viewModel.text)
        TextField("View B TextTwo", text: $viewModel.textTwo)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModelA = ViewModelA()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("View A Text", text: $viewModel.text)
            AddressView(addressModel: viewModel.addressViewModel)
            Button("Apply Button") {
                print("Button tapped!")
            }.disabled(!viewModel.isValid() || !viewModel.addressViewModel.isValid())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@StateObject` is for when you need a reference type in an `@State` it is not designed to be used as a legacy UIKit style view model object. To use SwiftUI effectively you'll need to learn the `View` struct and its `body`, `let`, `@Binding` and `@State` features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing ViewModelB in AddressView to be **Binding** not **ObservedObject**, as well, as making it in ViewModelA **Published** instead of **ObservedObject** solves the issue.

The reason for this is that SwiftUI's mechanism for observing changes only functions on one level of objects I guess, and doesn't automatically spread updates to objects that are nested within.

Please find full code below.

```
class ViewModelB: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    @Published var textTwo = ""
    
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        !text.isEmpty && !textTwo.isEmpty
    }
}

class ViewModelA: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    @Published var addressViewModel: ViewModelB = ViewModelB()
    
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        print("is Valid called")
        return !text.isEmpty && addressViewModel.isValid()
    }
}

struct AddressView: View {
    @Binding var viewModel: ViewModelB
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("View B Text", text: $viewModel.text)
        TextField("View B TextTwo", text: $viewModel.textTwo)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModelA = ViewModelA()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("View A Text", text: $viewModel.text)
            AddressView(viewModel: $viewModel.addressViewModel)
            Button("Apply Button") {
                print("Button tapped!")
            }.disabled(!viewModel.isValid() || !viewModel.addressViewModel.isValid())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You Ma'am are a legend, I have been staring at this all day and missed that, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should add `addressViewModel` in `ContentView` for the view to refresh when it changes, or you can follow this answer: [How to tell SwiftUI views to bind to nested ObservableObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58406402/13278922)

Also note that we use `@ObservedObject` exclusively in **SwiftUI** `View`s.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:

```
@Published var addressViewModel: ViewModelB = ViewModelB()
```

Instead of this:

```
@ObservedObject var addressViewModel: ViewModelB = ViewModelB()
```

Comment: Thank you,but this doesn't work unfortunately, the disabled state is still present on the button when all the textfields are filled out

Comment: I forgot to add @Binding, but I see you resolved this issue, so it's good! :)