# How does SwiftUI know what environmentObject to assign to which variable

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

Lets say I have a `View` with `Environment Object` like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    var viewModel: RegisterViewModel
}
```

and somewhere in ancestor I would provide this object like this:

```
NavigationView {
    LoginView()
}
.environmentObject(RegisterViewModel())
```

What is the mechanics of actually assigning this value to `var viewModel`. Nowhere in my code I needed to specify the name of variable, and yet it's correctly assigned. What will happened if I have few environment objects of the same type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EnvironmentObjects are identified by **type**.

SwiftUI just looks for environment variables for a specific type (here it's `RegisterViewModel`) and uses the first one it finds.

This code *puts* `RegisterViewModel` to the environment:

```
.environmentObject(RegisterViewModel())
```

Then, when building a View, SwiftUI looks for a `RegisterViewModel` type in the environment:

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: RegisterViewModel
```

More details:

- [How to set multiple EnvironmentObjects which are same type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57360838/8697793)
- [Why can't swiftui distinguish 2 different environment objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61804474/8697793)

Comment: What would happend if I define two variables of the same Type? Will they just both be assigned to the last one provided?

Comment: @DamianDudycz Please see [Why can't swiftui distinguish 2 different environment objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804474/why-cant-swiftui-distinguish-2-different-environment-objects) and [How to set multiple EnvironmentObjects which are same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360838/how-to-set-multiple-environmentobjects-which-are-same-type/57366566#57366566)